# Display png image xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.ios project running on Visual Studio for Imac.

I would like to display a png image file using XAML and C#.  Would it be best to use a dependency service to construct the image object in C#?

code snippet:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"> 
         <Image Name="MyImage" Width="180" />          
</StackLayout>
```

I placed my png file in the assets.xcassents folder. The file name is  picture.png.  How would I get this code to display in the xaml? What would the
code look like.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use the property `Source` of the `Image` tag in XAML. Than you are able to use the following code snippet:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"> 
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="picture.png" WidthRequest="180" />
</StackLayout>
```

And there was another issue in your XAML snippet, because the property `Width` is a readonly property for internal use by Xamarin.Forms. So if you want to specify the width of the image you must use the `WidthRequest` property.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the code blew up. The source image was placed in the Assets.xcassets folder under the AppIcon entry under the iPhone App iOS 7-11 image place holder.,  would this change the  Source="picture.png" statement?

Comment: In my last project I was working with the Resource folder, but take a look here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#asset-catalogs

Comment: @BobBarbara what's the exact problem are you facing? The image not show up or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Got the code working! Changed to BundleResouces and  do not copy for the property on the image file.  Also move  image File to a separate folder.